# Upload 2 file in 2 inpute

Tags: php

How to use 2 file controller in php?
In my form, first set input type="file" and then set input ="file".

```
<form action="" method="post">
input type="file" name="vid"> // for select vid and upload.
input type="file" name="pic"> // for select image and upload.
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

So, how i can use 2 controller in 1 form? I need that, and i want first, upload video, then, upload pic.
How can i create that in php?

Answer (score 0):

First, you should add an attribute named enctype to tag form:

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

This attribute allows form to upload files to server page when using POST request method.

In php server page you will dealing with each file speratly.
Each input file will be received as an array with five predefined indices, these indices contain all file data:

```
[file2] => Array(
    [name] => MyFile.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] =>/tmp/php/php6hst32
    [error] => UPLOAD_ERR_OK
    [size] => 98174
    )
```

You can browse these to know more details:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: That's great. Thanks.

Comment: Your are welcome

Comment: Can i use 2 input type="file"?  First, name="vid",,, second, name="pic". Or i must use 1 control and select 2file (video.mp4, picture.jpg), and use array for upload and save to database?

Comment: Can you send to my email or whatsapp his source code?